# HZ linux value different in two platforms will behave different with kernel timers?

Tags: timer, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I have two machines, one x86 machine with HZ value 1000, other embedded machine with HZ value 250. 
If i use kernel timers on both machines, with 
timer.expires = msecs_to_jiffies(x), 
So now time expiration time will be same 'x' milli seconds on both machines or do we need special care in these cases.

Comment: Examine the contents of **/proc/timer_list** to get the resolution of the timers on each system.

Answer (score 2):

If you use high resolution timers (kernel configuration), then the kernel timers use it and you'll get a correct result.
If you are not using HR timers, then on HZ=250 system the minimum time slice is 4 ms.  So if you sleep for less you'll wake up on the next timeslice. For example if you run a loop 1000 times sleeping for 1ms, the loop will end after 4 sec.